# Is it "out of question" or "out of the question"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, idioms, differences, definite-articles

Are they used in different contexts?
Those both of them use correct grammar?

[Google fight](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=%22out+of+question%22&word2=%22out+of+the+question%22) shows that "out of the question" appear 10 times more often than the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of THE question is the correct one in my opinion - I have never used this without the *the* but then I am not a native speaker.

Some sources mention that "Out of question" is an obsolete way of saying "Beyond doubt"

However we have both

OED: [Out of the question](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/156343?rskey=0z4jNP&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid27463136) vs [Out of question](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/133784?rskey=0z4jNP&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid32761458)

Also http://www.enotes.com/shakespeare-quotes/appendix-faux-out-question

Comment: But why are we using THE here?

Comment: Good question. Since it is _out of character_

Comment: Because "question" is usually a count noun, and so usually requires an article. "Beyond question" is a counter-example, though.

Comment: Actually, "beyond question" isn't a counter-example: "beyond" often takes a NP without an article, eg "beyond reach" = "beyond the reach of ... ".